# I spilled coffee on my Lenovo laptop's keyboard. What can I do?

Tags: laptop, keyboard, charger

I spilled coffee on my Lenovo laptop's keyboard. I turned it off and placed it upside down immediately.

After 2 hours of blowing it with a hairdryer and opening it to check if the coffee went through the motherboard (it didn't eventually) everything seemed to be ok. I opened it and for about 1 minute, the performance was good and worked perfect, except 2 keyboard keys.

After a minute it started slowing down a bit and making a weird "beeee" sound. I found out that this sound comes somewhere from the charger. After this, when I put the charger the led opens for about a second and then closes and doesn't charge.

Do I have to contact Lenovo to fix this, and make sure everything is ok? (both fir the keyboard and the charger) ?

Comment: Well, you did absolutely everything wrong. Take it to a repair shop. See https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/392675/119271 for what you *should* have done.

Comment: Yes, most probably you need professional support here. Unless it's very new or you've a specific reason I'd go for an independent repair shop, not to the retailer.

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid to say that two hours isn't long enough to ensure that the device was completely dry, and worse with coffee, especially if there is sugar, there might be other damage beyond an electrical short.

Either way it very much sounds like you have started the device too soon after the incident and the remaining liquid in side has caused a serious problem. It is unlikely to be something you will be able to fix yourself.

Your best bet will be to take it to a professional repair shop and explain exactly what happened. You will likely need a replacement mainboard but they will hopefully be able to salvage your data at least and other components.

If you try to return it to Lenovo it will be obvious to them that there has been liquid spilled on the device and they will not repair it under warranty, they will fix it for a charge though I am sure.

Comment: Finally I contacted Lenovo and I sent it today to fix it...Hope everything will be ok...

Comment: "If you try to return it to Lenovo it will be obvious to them that there has been liquid spilled on the device and they will not repair it under warranty" - Unless your warranty includes accidental damage protection.